# create graph in c++ from pb graph created in python containing new op

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow

How to link my libtensorflow_cc.so library with my custom op such that I can perform training in c++? My custom op is written in c++ and the graph that uses it is computed in python. I can load the pb graph but I can't create a graph.

I created a graph in python and saved as a protobuf file with write_graph. My graph uses a custom op whose kernel are written in c++ and registered as in https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/extend/adding_an_op#compile_the_op_using_your_system_compiler_tensorflow_binary_installation. I want to load my graph in c++ for training, the graph is loaded without warning but for "session->Create(graph_def)" I get an error:

```
Non-OK-status: session->Create(graph_def) status: Not found: 
Op type not registered 'MyOp' in binary running on user-linux. 
Make sure the Op and Kernel are registered in the binary running in this process. 
Note that if you are loading a saved graph which used ops from tf.contrib,
accessing (e.g.) `tf.contrib.resampler` should be done before importing the graph,
as contrib ops are lazily registered when the module is first accessed.
```

I'm not using anything from tf.contrib. This is an easier version of my c++ code:

```
    std::string graph_definition = "Mygraph.pb";
    Session* session; 
    GraphDef graph_def;
    SessionOptions opts;


    //load graph 
    TF_CHECK_OK(ReadBinaryProto(Env::Default(), graph_definition, &graph_def));
    // create a new session
    TF_CHECK_OK(NewSession(opts, &session));
    // Load graph into session
    TF_CHECK_OK(session->Create(graph_def));
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need to load your library using `TF_LoadLibrary` defined in [`c/c_api.h`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.9.0/tensorflow/c/c_api.h). In [`c/c_api_test.cc`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.9.0/tensorflow/c/c_api_test.cc) you have an example of how it would work:

```
// Load the library.
TF_Status* status = TF_NewStatus();
TF_Library* lib =
    TF_LoadLibrary("tensorflow/c/test_op.so", status);
TF_Code code = TF_GetCode(status);
string status_msg(TF_Message(status));
TF_DeleteStatus(status);
ASSERT_EQ(TF_OK, code) << status_msg;
```

The function loads the library and registers the ops and kernels it defines within the TensorFlow runtime.

---

*EDIT:*

Okay so technically the important function to load a library is `tensorflow::LoadLibrary`, defined in [`core/framework/load_library.cc`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.9.0/tensorflow/core/framework/load_library.cc). However, this function 1) does not seem to be publicly declared in any header (indeed, [`c/c_api.cc`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.9.0/tensorflow/c/c_api.cc) contains a declaration of this function for internal use) 2) has rather obscure parameters. As far as I can see, the C API seems to be currently the simpler way to load a library in a C++ program, even if you have to take care to destroy the objects appropriately (i.e. call `TF_DeleteLibraryHandle`). By the way, there does not seem to be a way to unload the library either; you can destroy the library handle object, but that will not unload the library.

Comment: I solved my problem just by including the my_op.cc header files in the c+ code. The warning was looking for the REGISTER_OP(my_op) label. I think  the method proposed by @jdehesa is necessary to build the graph in C++, but it's not if I only want to run the graph that was previously computed in python, right?

Comment: @Ceveloper That's interesting, I assumed that the registrations that the library loading function performs were necessary in any case, but if simply including the header with the declarations work that is definitely much simpler.